# Edit a 3 year old answer or create a new answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, outdated-information

It is well known that questions using `mysql_*` on Stack Overflow have been getting the canned

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

treatment.

So when I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1685860/561731) with almost 60 thousand views and all of the answers referenced the old (soon to be removed) `mysql_*` extension for php I thought that a new answer should be put there to show what one should do currently as opposed to editing the answer that was currently accepted and layed untouched for 3 years.

I stupidly asked chat to upvote my answer and downvote the current accepted answer (which is what was done for other answers that have come deprecated and in need of being replaced).

Instead of people helping me out, I was berated and told that I should not have done that etc.

I even got a comment on my answer asking **why** I did not edit the original accepted answer.

---

I did not feel that editing a really old answer was acceptable, ***especially*** changing it that much!

If I was wrong on my approach i will gladly delete my answer and edit the accepted one, I am just asking for what should have been the correct thing for me to do (when it came to that question, not to chat) and what should be done in the future if a user finds an outdated accepted answer.

Comment: *Related: [How appropriate is it to ask for upvotes in chat?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160194/how-appropriate-is-it-to-ask-for-upvotes-in-chat)*

Comment: @MadaraUchiha this has **nothing** to do with chat!

Comment: No, which is why I didn't post it as an answer, but as a related comment. Please refrain from attacking people, we bite.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I am not attacking anyone. I mentioned no names in my post here. (although you did by posting that link).

Comment: Keep in mind that sub-communities are allowed to develop their own standards for those aspects of SO that are subjective.  If the PHP tag as a whole feels that editing all `mysql_*` used in answers (or possibly just the answers of canonical questions) to newer counterparts are acceptable edits then that's that communities prerogative.

Comment: Did you explain your reasoning when you asked for upvotes in chat? Although I think editing would probably be the right way to go, I can see the sense in asking for help to promote updated/correct information.

Comment: @JoshCaswell it was moved to bin by the PHP admin... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6894049#6894049 still do not know why....

Comment: Let's be clear. You did **NOT** get berated for adding the answer. You got berated for posting *"Upvote my answer and downvote the accepted one"*. **That** is very much frowned upon (and discouraged severely). The answer itself was never a topic of discussion... Additionally *still do not know why*? Really? After it was explained in chat by almost every active person in the room that explicitly asking for upvotes or downvotes is not allowed in that room... And you still don't know why? Either you don't want to listen, or you don't care. Both bother me...

Comment: Off topic - it stands to reason the entire SO question could be burninated, seeing as Googling `PHP: how to get last inserted ID of a table?` leads to the canonical manual entries for both `mysql_*` and PDO. But seeing as our overlords have denied us the "General Reference" close reason...

Comment: @Pekka so let's close and delete it ^_^

Comment: If there's a duplicate question with newer, more appropriate answers, just close this question as a dupe of that one.  I'd be disinclined to delete an answer with that many links; better to just reference a better answer so people realize that it's not appropriate instead of just getting a 404.

Comment: I think you did it right, that's way too much of an edit.

Comment: @LanceRoberts thank you. Can you post that as a long type answer? ^_^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that was the appropriate way to 'fix' the question.  Adding an answer is fine, it's way too much of an edit difference from the original accepted answer.

It probably would have been better to just post the link to the answer in chat, and not ask for the upvote.  That's the way I usually handle answers or questions I feel need a little promotion.

Comment: Yea, that probably would have been a better approach, but that did not happen, and I paid for it....

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA It's interesting to see that you accepted the answer that said "Your way was correct, but it might have been better to do this" even if it is not the answer that a large part of the community seems to think to be right...

Answer (score 19):

The original creator of the accepted answer is active on SO so suggesting him (in a comment) to update his answer is the way to go.

Comment: This is also fine, but sometimes you don't get a response from people.

Answer (score 6):

Posting a new answer is fine, that's why we allow for multiple answers.

Bringing the answer in question (pun intended) to the community (or sub-community, for that matter) is fine. That's part of the reason we have chat in the first place.

Promoting your own posts for the sake of reputation, is not fine. And that's the feeling we got from your messages, even if you didn't originally intend it.

---

All in all, I see nothing wrong with presenting a hard-worked, well-written, well-explained answer to the community for review and upvoting. I personally don't think that the specific answer you've linked to meets any of these criteria. You could (and should!) have solved it by simply pinging the OP, or even, God forbid, as a 40k user, edit the accepted question yourself. If you genuinely want to help, make the important information most visible.

Comment: I never said **anything** about reputation. The other answer is wrong for the current usage of PHP.

Comment: The primary problem that I have with editing the answer (given my rather limited knowledge of PHP) is that it would be a very non-trivial edit that would be significantly changing the *content* of the post, which is really not appropriate for edits.  That is, unless the answer was CW (it's not).

Comment: Also the answer with the most upvotes is not a high quality, involved, or detailed answer for which most of the content is worth saving.  It's nothing more than a link to a method, and if that method is no longer appropriate, then 100% of that answer is invalid and would need to be rewritten.  If the code snippet to be updated was only 20% of the answer I'd be more inclined to try to find an appropriate way to edit the answer.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table/14061088#14061088) is the answer in question. I don't think that he put so much effort into it, that it's worth an upvote. It's technically correct, yes. How *useful* is it? Not as much. And by repeating himself over the manner, he didn't exactly help himself.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha how correct is the accepted answer? That just gives how to do it for `mysql_*`?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: An **accepted answer** is just that. It's accepted by the OP as the answer which helped *him* the most. Do not mistake it as the **correct** answer, because it may not always be the case.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha so why should I even edit an answer that may not even be **correct**?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha If you feel the content that he's providing is not of particularly high quality or useful information, all the more reason he shouldn't edit it into a highly upvoted and visited answer that entirely replaces the content of the previous answer.  Just to be clear, I'm not saying that Neal's answer should be upvoted, I'm just saying I don't think he should have edited that content into the top answer.

Comment: @amanaP define "correct". Deceze's answer was clearly correct for the purposes of the OP at the time he accepted it. He didn't *want* to use PDO, and for the mysql extension, deceze's answer is still valid. I would have left it alone.

Comment: @Pekka and if the question was asked now? deceze's answer would be downvoted to oblivion. I do not see your point....

Comment: @amanaP so you propose downvoting all answers involving old libraries because we shouldn't use them any more, and replacing them with answers involving new libraries? I don't think that question needed fixing. (Except maybe burnination - IMO)

Comment: @Pekka that is what the PHP room has been doing for a while. Putting out tons of cv and delete requests on old questions/answers.

Comment: @amanaP but there's a vast difference between that and what we're discussing here, isn't there?

Comment: @Pekka not really...

Comment: @Pekka Well, the first thing that comes to mind is that this question has a lot of views, and likely external links/references to it.  Such content should probably not be deleted.  Closure may be appropriate though.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA So you think closing/deleting is the same as posting a new answer, upvoting that answer a lot, and downvoting all of the old answers?  It's worth discussing which is appropriate, but they're clearly different options...

Comment: @Servy but it answers a question (badly) that you can Google by entering the question's title, and you are led to the *canonical references* in the respective manuals. How does this question make the Internet a better place? If anything, it makes it a slightly *worse* one. (I see your point re incoming links, though. This is a general thing)

Comment: @Servy that could be a whole other discussion...

Comment: @ircmaxell Well, to keep things on topic, it would appear that the PHP chatroom felt that editing the top answer, in entirely, would be appropriate.  I wouldn't.  Was that chatroom expressing the general opinion of the PHP community, in which case it would be contrary to general SO guidelines, or were they misrepresenting that community?

Comment: @Servy: No, the chatroom did not fel that editing the top answer would be appropriate. I was there (I was the one that moved the chat messages, sparking this whole thing). The room objected to the *upvote my answer and downvote the accepted one* [post](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6894049#6894049). That's what we *flipped out over*. Someone misinterpreted it, and made this message and insinuated the editing. In fact, I don't like the editing of messages for content in general...

Comment: @ircmaxell All right, that clears up that tangent nicely.  So that brings us to, "How would you suggest addressing the problems of this question?"  Do you think it's appropriate to close it, should a proper, high quality, answer using recent technologies be posted and voted to the top, would you just comment on the top answer for him to update it (and what might you do if he was inactive, or choose not to change it).

Comment: @Servy: As far as addressing the problems here, I see three solutions.  The first is to add a high quality answer, and let the community move it into place. Since the community can't de-accept an answer, that won't always work (especially in cases where the OP is gone). The second is to close it as a dup. But that requires a canonical answer (which we could find). The third, is to allow us to [add a general reference close type](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160565/147370). That way something like this which is basically just a docs regurgitation can be closed against docs instead of a dup.

Comment: @ircmaxell Sounds like we agree entirely then.  (Given that option 3 isn't currently an available option, so one of the other two would need to be used for this case.)

Comment: @ircmaxell Since you've cleared that up nicely I've deleted that comment.  I was letting an old question bleed into this one.

Answer (score 0):

It completely invalid to edit like this  what you need do is  ask to OP  to edit. As in your [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158467/edit-privilege-miscellaneous-use) and there is comment for that

> [image]

Comment: Could you please rephrase that? It isn't entirely clear what you're saying.

Comment: i am saying that ..that same user telling that its invalid .. in a answer now did same thing ..

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean: Panama advocated commenting and asking the original answerer to update the answer, then went ahead and did the opposite.

Comment: @Asad I did **not** post a duplicate answer with the same information. I posted a **new** answer with new information. **BIG** difference.

Comment: @Asad exactly ... also he did rollback

Comment: @NullPointer rollback what? I did not edit any answers!

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA you rollback my edit and than post is not useful  for future visitor that why i have to give a new answer ... and what about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1685867/1723893 edit this is same case ..

Comment: @NullPointer lol your edit was just adding links. you edit (and answer) added **nothing** new.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA not only link but also information ... also if i added only link its completely according to stackoverflo check [to add related resources or hyperlinks](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) in edit privilege page.. what you need to do is ask to op first to add about this ...... and you didnot ...

Comment: @NullPointer your edit was trivial and added nothing to the original post that could not have just been a comment.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I'm not entirely clear on the background of this, but in the quoted answer you are claiming NullPointer added too much information, yet you are also saying he did not add enough information. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @Asad thats exactly i am telling ...