# Asking possibly "trivial" questions to increase SO's knowledge

Tags: discussion, questions

I know that SO is supposed to basically be a knowledge repository when it comes to programming. It's also important to do your research before asking a question.

I notice there are several [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986925/declaring-array-variables) that [could be looked up else where](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays.html) fairly easy but are still seen as viable for SO. Personally, I like to look at SO questions for said research (though I'll certainly look else where) because the answers here are usually fairly comprehensive, you don't have to dig for them, and they're written in an easy to understand format.

Is it wrong to ask questions that can be found else where in an attempt to increase the answers SO has available? I'm specifically interested in answers that are already documented else where but fall in grey area between absolute basic (which should be available at thousands of locations) and more intermediate (which may have several easy to find resources).

Comment: Related: I asked the same on a beta site [ask-even-if-the-answer-exists-online](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65/)

Comment: The linked question garnered a grand total of two votes in three years, so I'm not sure it could be considered "good."

Comment: @GeorgeCummins fair enough, I'll change the wording

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Overflow should not be a replacement for a search engine.

Of course it's totally okay to ask questions that exist elsewhere, but: if the answer to a question can be unequivocally answered with a simple search that leads to official or quasi-official documentation  ("How do I concatenate two strings in JavaScript?"), it should not probably not exist on Stack Overflow.

In my opinion, trivial SO content [already tends to clog search engine results.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160565/g)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922647/how-do-i-combine-2-javascript-variables-into-a-string

Answer (score 5):

It's not important for every single nugget of programming knowledge to exist on Stack Overflow.  It's purpose is to cover information not found elsewhere, not to have a monopoly on information.  If the answer to a given question is easily discoverable elsewhere on the web (regardless of the difficulty level of the question) then it is not a good SO question.

Now, questions like these get asked *many* times a day, and their reception does vary.  Some people really like to see these questions even though they are easily discoverable elsewhere, even though many do not, so while it is uncommon, it's also not unheard of to see very simple questions for which the answers can be easily found on other sites to be open or have some upvotes.  While this does happen from time to time, I would discouraging you from posting a question if you know that it's easy to find the answer; there's so much information that *not* easy to find that, if nothing else, you can come up with better uses of your time.

Comment: as a follow up, if its available, but difficult to find, would you consider that good question?

Comment: @Daniel I wouldn't consider it an automatically bad question, the way that I would if it was easily discoverable.  Obviously there's a lot more than just discoverability to writing a good question.

Comment: `It's not important for every single nugget of programming knowledge to exist on Stack Overflow.` - Blaspheme!

Answer (score 2):

Do not like.

Stack Overflow gets enough questions by the day. We know what programming problems people are actually facing, because people search for, find, or ask (over and over and over again) about those programming problems every second of every day.

We do not need people guessing what information Stack Overflow *doesn't* have and trying to fill in the gaps. We have it. If not, we'll get it as soon as somebody actually needs it. We're just that good at what we do. What if nobody ever asks? Then obviously nobody needed it, and you just wasted your valuable time.

Spend your time answering questions that already exist and helping clean up content that is not up to our standards or is duplicated (we get a lot of that, too).

---

tl;dr: If you ask a trivial question that is useful for no one or I can easily find the answer on Google, I will downvote that question without sympathy.

Answer (score 0):

The word "trivial" really has two meanings in common usage:  one is "easy" and the other is "unimportant".

If a question is trivial because it's unimportant, that comes pretty close to the criterion for "too localized" used to close some questions.

If a question is easy because finding the answer is easy, even using an "obvious" search key, then that's a question of how much value the added answer in SE adds, versus how much clutter the Q and the A add.

I would say that if a Wikipedia article gives a thorough answer to the question as usually asked, and if most seekers are likely to find the Wikipedia answer, that's enough reason to just let it be.

The tricky case is when a good answer is easily found if and only if the question is asked in precisely the right way, but most seekers are going to ask in a more vague way, because they don't know what they are looking for.  Some of those might be usefully included here.  Others not.