# What happens if the OP doesn't know English language yet post a question with mere code?

Tags: discussion, review, non-english-speakers

Does SE have any sort of "assisting measure" for those who wants to post and communicate questions in English, who are unable to communicate in English?

There could be just a code without a question. Even there's a question, then such OP might not be able to follow up with comments in order to arrive in the answer. Even the answer is provided, there could be an issue again.

Or

1. Are we assuming "Online-Translators" would have been used?
2. Will the `review` section have a special filter for editing such question using native community members and then followed up with *experienced* community members (who have done high quality reviews) to approve the validity of the question's contents?

Comment: Stack Overflow *requires* that you use English. If someone is kind enough to translate then the OP got lucky, but there is no official support for non-english speakers.

Comment: I was just seeing [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504990/loading-10-minits-1100-records) and it really looks like the case...

Comment: What makes you think anyone looked at that post because the OP doesn't speak english? People looked at that post perhaps because they are looking for new posts on the tags, and they helped clean up the post as they would any other badly written and formatted post. It was rightfully closed as unclear (there is hardly a question there).

Comment: There will be Stack Overflow sites in different languages. There is already in [Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/) and plans to create more. (Turkish, Russian, Spanish will come very soon)

Comment: @MartijnPieters `It was rightfully closed as unclear(there's hardly a question there)` - I understand the rules here. However can't the reason behind `no question` due to `no English knowledge`? Just my visual...

Comment: @bonCodigo: No, that was a low-quality post. It would have been a low-quality post even if the OP spoke english. There is hardly enough *text* there to make any claims about the OP's grasp of the language.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well having questions distributted by language in future, could also mean...people who only speak English, may lose the chance to see really great questions and answers :)

Comment: True @bonCodigo and it was discussed here already, let me find it... weird, nothing yet except [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218055/is-it-ok-to-crosspost-stack-overflow-questions-now-that-the-portuguese-so-is-op). Feel free to start such a discussion!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Also discussed [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moderators generally try to help, as do members of the wider community.

Patience for new members of the community is variable - we try and give leeway for people who do not have English as their first language, but sometimes we don't do so well.

Make no assumptions - just guide and help them.

Answer (score 1):

While I think that code-only answer **is** an answer, if it answers the question (when OP asks how to do something, not how it works) I can't imagine any single case where we could have code-only question. How should it look like? A block of code without any explanation? It's unclear what is asked here, it's even worse than 'my code not working' description.

The OP must be albe to understand English in order to ask in English-language site. How else it should be supported to work?

It isn't in fact the most important thing if OP is going to understand answer. There are many brilliant answers which are clearly misunderstood by OP, because OP fails minimal understanding of the topic, but are nevertheless brillian answers.

In end effect the only thing that matters is **will the question an answer be valuable to community**. Non-English language question on English-language site will have little value to English-speaking community.